# What is the best way to synchronize messages?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a script with two subscribers. The general way to do this is of course

```
subN = rospy.Subscriber("topicN", TypeN,CallbackN)
```

so I have two callbacks: Callback1 for topic1 and Callback2 for topic2

However my objective is to use the information of  *both* these topics to generate (and publish) another message.

I am wondering how should I proceed to use both of these messages? Where should I put the code? In a third callback function? How can I synchronize receiving these two messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374883/what-is-the-best-way-to-synchronize-messages?/) by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2021-03-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-29**:
@Kansai: I'm trying to figure out what leads people to post new questions on topics already discussed on ROS Answers. There are many duplicates of your question (and of @Rufus answer).

Could you write a bit about how you approached posting here? Did you search before you posted? If so: how did you search? With which tools? If not: why not? If you did search, and did find previous Q&As: did those not answer your question? Could you describe why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a `message_filter` for this.  If you want to synchronize by time, you can use the [TimeSynchronizer](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer) or ApproximateTimeSynchronizer.

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2021-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-03-29**:
Thanks! I found this http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-03-29**:
Mmmm. I tried the example in the link and eventhough both topics are publishing (I checked this) the callback function is not being called. then I found this https://answers.ros.org/question/172676/solved-problem-with-ros-message-filters/